# Addition of Polynomials : SAT LEVEL 2

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$ (3x + 2)^2 + (3y+4)^2 = 0 $$ 
What is $ y+x $?

The answer is $-2$. Id like to know how. Thank you.

Comment: For future reference, algebra is fundamentally different from linear algebra.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order for the two squares to be $0$. Both expressions $(3x+2)^2$ and $(3y+4)^2$ have to be $0$.

$$3x+2=0$$
$$3y+4=0$$

Add Both equations $3(x+y)+6=0$. I leave the rest to you.

Comment: They can only be 0 and not compensating each other (-a and +a) because they are squares and thus $\ge0$